# Lettuce API getting into periodic TimeoutException Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, lettuce

We have 10 node (5 Masters, 5 Read Replicas) AWS Redis Cluster. We use Lettuce API. We are using Lettuce API non pool configuration and Async calls. Almost once every week we get into issue where we get continuous TimoutExceptions for few minutes. We are expecting this as a network issue, but networking team has found no issue with network. What can be possible solution?

```
private LettuceConfigWithoutPool(RedisClusterConfig pool) {
    if (lettuceConfigWithoutPoolInstance != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the single instance of this class.");
    }
    List<RedisURI> redisURIS = new RedisURIBuilder.Builder(pool)
            .withPassword()
            .withTLS()
            .build();

    ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions clusterTopologyRefreshOptions = new ClusterTopologyBuilder.Builder(pool)
            .setAdaptiveRefreshTriggersTimeoutInMinutes()
            .build();

    ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
            .topologyRefreshOptions(clusterTopologyRefreshOptions)
            .build();
    RedisClusterClient redisClusterClient = ClusterClientProvider.buildClusterClient(redisURIS, clusterClientOptions);
    StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, Object> statefulRedisClusterConnection = redisClusterClient.connect(new SerializedObjectCodec());

    statefulRedisClusterConnection.setReadFrom(ReadFromArgumentProvider.getReadFromArgument(pool.getReadFrom()));
    this.command = statefulRedisClusterConnection.async();

    
}
```

Comment: Can you please point to the AWS Docs that suggest using this API for a specific use case.

Comment: @smac2020, I haven't came across aws Docs talking about Lettuce API

Comment: You mean ElastiCache or your own Redis on EC2? What timeout setting are you using? What's the error you are getting?